# view the real htaccessed link

Tags: .htaccess

how can i view the real URL without the functionality of .htaccess rewrite file ?

while using url rewrite with the .htaccess file you able to see sites like this :

example.com/i/154/b/6574534

i want to see the "source" of the url , such as

example.com/index.php?i=15&b=6574534

Comment: What is the "real" URL?  Where do you want to view it?

Comment: @tandu i updated the post , check it out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to reverse the URL rewriting, without having server-level access to the server you are interested in.  If this is the case, what you're asking for is not possible unless the server provides an API, a custom HTTP header in the response, another link on the page, or some other method to find the non-rewritten URL.  The ability to do otherwise would defeat many purposes of URL rewriting.

Comment: If it's nice enough to use i/n/b/n, you could just type in example.com/index.php?i=n&b=n and it probably won't clean up the URL for you. Of course, I can't think of any reason to really do this.